# How to load TestNG config within an executable JAR?

Tags: java, maven, jar, testng, executable-jar

I have an shaded executable jar created by a Maven build.  Within I have a main class that executes and attempts to run a collection of TestNG tests.  It runs until it it attempts to load the xml config files for the tests.  The steps within the main class are:

```
    suites.add("testng-A.xml");
    suites.add("testng-B.xml");

    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
```

The problem is that I cannot get TestNG to successfully find the xml files.  I receive a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: testng-a.xml (No such file or directory)" error.  The location of the files in the JAR are:

```
    /com/address/MyMainClass 
    /testng-a.xml
    /testng-b.xml
```

I am running the jar with the following command:

```
    java -jar uber.jar
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you make the path absolute?

Comment: It looks like this is a known problem: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/52

Comment: I tried hard coding the path to "/Users/myDevDirectory/target/uber.jar!/testng-a.xml" as an experiment, which did not work.  Was that what you were referring too?

Comment: The issue linked above 1) has nothing to do with this problem and 2) is closed and resolved. I answered TERACyTE on the mailing-list, see the link below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this cannot be done within the JAR.  The testng xml configs cannot be loaded in this manner.  The files need to be external from the JAR before loading.

http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/ad7e33342125e717?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: In my java code, I copied the internal resource to a temporary folder, and used TestListenerAdapter to run the tests using the xml definition.